# pkgdown workflow fails to deploy gh pages

Tags: r, github-actions, github-pages, r-package, pkgdown

I setup for my R package repository a `pkgdown` workflow. 
The `.github/workflows/pkgdown.yaml` file:

```
on:
  push:
    branches: [main, master]
  release:
    types: [published]
  workflow_dispatch:

name: pkgdown

jobs:
  pkgdown:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      GITHUB_PAT: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-pandoc@v1

      - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-r@v1
        with:
          use-public-rspm: true

      - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-r-dependencies@v1
        with:
          extra-packages: pkgdown
          needs: website

      - name: Deploy package
        if: contains(env.isPush, 'true')
        run: |
          git config --local user.email "actions@github.com"
          git config --local user.name "GitHub Actions"
          Rscript -e 'pkgdown::deploy_to_branch(new_process = FALSE)'
```

The `pkgdown` workflow works fine, but it fails to update the GitHub pages. 
I setup the `gh-pages` branch as explained in the GitHub documentation, so the workflow `pages-build-deployment` is present, but when I push on `main` branch it doesn't run.

Answer (score 0):

I realized the problem was in the `if: contains(env.isPush, 'true')` line. The condition is never `true` nor `false`, since there is no attribute `isPush` under `env`, hence the lines

```
        run: |
          git config --local user.email "actions@github.com"
          git config --local user.name "GitHub Actions"
          Rscript -e 'pkgdown::deploy_to_branch(new_process = FALSE)'
```

were never executed.

To solve the problem, either modify the `env` part:

```
    env:
      GITHUB_PAT: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      isPush: ${{ github.event_name == 'push' }}
```

or remove the `if` condition before the `run` command.